# How to prevent _Excel_RangeRead() converting comma to decimal point?

Tags: excel, number-formatting, autoit

I read values from Excel using [`_Excel_RangeRead()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Excel_RangeRead.htm) to paste them into a program that only accepts comma as decimal separator.

I have 3,14 in Excel, but `_Excel_RangeRead()` converts this to 3.14. How to prevent this or convert these back?

Answer (score 0):

If you do it this way it should work: Use parameter 3

```
#include <Excel.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
Local $oExcel = _Excel_Open(False)
If @error Then Exit MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Excel UDF: _Excel_RangeRead Example", "Error creating the Excel application object." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)
Local $oWorkbook = _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel, "c:\Autoit\ForumTests\ExcelRead.xlsx")
If @error Then
    _Excel_Close($oExcel)
    Exit
EndIf

Local $aResult = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, 'A1', 3)
If @error Then Exit MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Excel UDF: _Excel_RangeRead Example 3", "Error reading from workbook." & @CRLF & "@error = " & @error & ", @extended = " & @extended)
ConsoleWrite($aResult & @CRLF)
```